# Conditional AND in select statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have a select statement in a stored procedure and `@date` is the parameter for the stored procedure.

This is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_A a               
INNER JOIN vw_B b ON a.id = b.id              
WHERE 
    a.imdt IS NULL     
    AND a.appflg = 'Y'                
    AND a.last_dt > cast(@date as datetime);
```

Now the table `vw_A` also has a `Date` column `prgDate`.

This column could be `null`, or it will contain a `datetime` value.

I want to change the above select query in such a way that

- if `prgDate` is `null`, then the above select statement uses the condition `(AND a.last_dt > cast(@date as datetime))`
- else the select statement should use `prgDate` value instead of `last_dt` in the condition: `(AND a.prgDate > cast(@date as datetime))`

How could I achieve this in the select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_A a               
INNER JOIN vw_B b ON a.id = b.id              
WHERE 
    a.imdt IS NULL     
    AND a.appflg = 'Y'                
    AND ISNULL(a.prgDate, a.last_dt) > cast(@date as datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you instead, there mean...?

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_A a               
     INNER JOIN vw_B b ON a.id = b.id              
WHERE a.imdt IS NULL     
  AND a.appflg = 'Y'                
  AND ((a.prgDate IS NULL AND a.last_dt > CAST(@date AS datetime))
   OR  a.last_dt IS NULL > CAST(@date AS datetime);
```

Comment: Hi larnu the last_dt will not be null it will always contain values. In general I should select based on last_dt unless the prgDate is not NULL .

Comment: So... more like that, @Ramaswamy ? Your attempt to describe your goal (in your question) isn't very clear; it's very confusing to read. If this isn't correct, please reword it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Thanks much for the help @Larnu